# What is the difference between lvfs and vendor-directory?

Tags: firmware, discover-software-center

What is the difference between lvfs and vendor-directory?

KDE has recently added support for lvfs. That is enabled by default, but when looking at the software sources I also see 'vendor-directory - Vendor (Automatic)'[image]

I have not been able to find what vendor-directory is or what it offers extra in relation to lvfs. Does anyone know what the difference is?

Comment: @David That question is about directory structures. There might be a relation, but I don't know what it is. All firmware in the Linux *Vendor* Firmware Service (lvfs) is provided by vendors.

Answer (score 3):

KDE added support for Fwupd. LVFS comes with Fwupd.

LVFS is used for those vendors that are supported. The list of vendors can be found on the fwup [website](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/vendors/).

If your vendor is NOT on that list you need to enable `vendor-directory`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if `vendor-directory` is also managed by lvfs? I wonder what firmware is in vendor-directory and who puts it in there.